# arima_model.plot_predict() shows different results than arima_model.fitted_values

Tags: python, time-series, arima

I am trying to construct the arima model.
When I write

```
arima_fit.plot_predict()
plt.show()
```

I get this result which is quite good. [image]

But. When I try to calculate the RMSE with actual df['y'] values and arima_fit.fitted_values I get values around 0. Like 0.04 ,-0.1 etc
The same with the arima_fit.predict() values.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I found an answer. The d component of arima means the differencing, if to set it to 1 it will give you a detrended value.
ARIMA() gives you the values without trend and seasonality added. Indeed if to detract the seasonality and trend from the original series we will get the next picture. Or as an alternative we can use the SArima model which takes into account also the seasonality. (Indeed Seasonal Arima).
Interesting fact.. The RMSE of the detrended and deseasonalized with ARIMA (d=1) is lower than either arima (d=0) and sarima models
[image]